# Parse Error: Parse Error In Connecting To Database Script

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone tell me what the parse error is in this script!, would much appreciate it.

```
mysql_connect ('localhost','root','root'); or die ("mysql_error"());
```

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: hope you get the solution from answer below. But I recommend you to use more safer extension like `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `;`  after `mysql_connect` and also the quotes in `mysql_error()`.

```
mysql_connect ('localhost','root','root') or die (mysql_error());
```

For reference: [Connecting to database](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/database_connection.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Remove the first semicolon. `; or` is not valid.

Also, you shouldn't typically be quoting `mysql_error`:

```
mysql_connect ('localhost','root','root') or die(mysql_error());
```